# RedbeanPHP like for nodejs

Tags: node.js, orm, redbean, on-the-fly

I like the way RedBeanPHP works, but it is written in PHP. so my question is: Is there any on-the-fly ORM for NodeJs, that works like RedbeanPHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want [Tayr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Tayr) it's still in development, but you can give it a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently porting RedBeanPHP into Node.js which is named RedBeanNode. It has basic features of RedBeanPHP and the api design is very similar to RedBeanPHP.

Check out on:
https://github.com/louislam/redbean-node